# Firebase cross-service Security Rules not working - no prompt to add permission

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, firebase-security

The new Firebase cross-service Security Rules that help validate Firestore docs mentioned in https://firebase.blog/posts/2022/09/announcing-cross-service-security-rules seem great but I am not able to get the Rules console to ask for the permission. There is no error in building the Rules page, but there is an error because of insufficient permission any time I use the firestore.get() feature in the rules when fetching the images. Additionally, my IAM page does not have the correct role listed in https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/manage-deploy#manage_permissions_for_cross-service and I am not able to find the Role "Firebase Rules Firestore Service Agent" to add it manually.

Anyone run into this yet?

From rules in Firebase storage console

```
match /projects/{projectId} {
  allow read: if true;
  allow write: if firestore.get(/databases/(default)/documents/projects/$(projectId)).data.owner == request.auth.uid
}
```

From Google Cloud IAM
[image]

Comment: Are you prompted to enable the role when deploying using the [Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli)? (Note: you'll need the latest version)

Comment: I'm not familiar with how to deploy firebase storage rules through CLI, so I haven't tried that yet

Comment: Give that a shot, but do note that deploying from the CLI will overwrite whatever Rules you've set in the Console, so make sure they match before doing the deploy (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#deployment_conflicts). If that doesn't work, there may be something else going on specifically with your project, in which case it would be best to contact [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support)

Answer (score 2):

*Firebaser here*

There was an issue with the rollout of this feature in the Firebase console that we've *just* fixed (thanks for catching this!) Please try deploying your Rules again -- you should be prompted to configure the project as expected.

For anyone else experiencing issues, the notes in the comments on the question do apply -- you can deploy cross-service rules from the CLI as well.

Comment: All good now, thank you!